# "Multidimensional Arrays" | "Data frame"

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, rbind

I´m new in R. 
¿How can I work "multidimensional Arrays" as "data frame" to use functions, such as "as.data.frame" and "rbind"? Thanks in advance.

I am analyzing a database that includes observations from 2011 to 2013. I have used the following code:

## Summary of LOS by year

```
a <- tapply(stroke$los, stroke$year, summary) 
loss <- as.data.frame(rbind(los2011 <- c(2011, 
         a[["2011"]][["1st Qu."]], a[["2011"]][["Median"]],
            a[["2011"]][["3rd Qu."]]), 
  los2012 <- c(2012, a[["2012"]][["1st Qu."]], 
      a[["2012"]][["Median"]], a[["2012"]][["3rd Qu."]]), 
  los2013 <- c(2013, a[["2013"]][["1st Qu."]],
     a[["2013"]][["Median"]], a[["2013"]][["3rd Qu."]])))
```

But, I obtain this.

```
 1 2011 
 2 2012
 3 2013
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: probably the quickest thing is `reshape2::melt()`

Comment: Thank you very much for your support to follow learning!

Comment: start by using `=` rather than `<-` to name components within your `rbind()` statement ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to create something like a "multidimensional array" (e.g., Matlab) is to use `tidyr::nest()`.

Since `nest()` allows you to store a list of data frames in a column of a data frame (multidimensional), you can apply "data frame" functions to that column.

Here is some information about this function/package/approach:

- Release of [tidyr](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/) 0.4.0 when `nest()` and the concept of *nested data frames* is first introduced.
- An [explanation](http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/nest.html) of the `nest()` function.
- Creating list-columns with nesting as explained in the online book *[R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html#creating-list-columns)*.

Also, since you are new to R and it seems you are keen to the data frame format, you may want to look at the tidyverse--which is a collection of R packages designed for data science and a data frame-like mentality. See [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/) for the package website.